# Calculated value not being updated correctly using donejs

Tags: javascript, canjs, donejs

I have standard donejs project with a component and a model both created using the default generators like this:

```
donejs add component storyBoard story-board
donejs add supermodel story
```

I left a sample project here: https://github.com/riescorp/donejs-promise-iterate

If you run this example using `donejs develop` and go to http://localhost:8080 you'll see something like this:

[image]

The problem is that whenever you change a value of the number of pages (input boxes) for any story, the sum won't update its value. I tried almost everything, from promises to already-resolved-promises but nothing seems to do the trick.

Somehow it seems that when any of those values change, there is no update trigger at all. I also tried setting the results as a List (`can.List`) but with no luck.

Comment: There was a discussion in gitter, you can check it out here: https://gitter.im/donejs/donejs?at=586fd523db9cafe9183ba46b

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem seems to be that `elem.pages` should be `elem.attr("pages")`.

Here's a version of the code that works for me:

```
export const ViewModel = Map.extend({
  define: {
    storyPromise: {
      get: function() {
        return Story.getList({});
      }
    },
    stories: {
      get: function(last, resolve) {
        this.attr("storyPromise").then(resolve);
      }
    },
    sum2: {
      get: function() {
        var total = 0;
        if (this.attr('stories') !== undefined) {
          this.attr('stories').each(function(elem) {
            total += parseInt( elem.attr("pages") );
          });
        }
        return total;
      }
    }
  }
});
```

You have to use `.attr`, otherwise, `sum2` doesn't know when the `pages` property changes.